# How to use lambda to change the values in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've tried to scale the values ​​in the dataframe by a factor of 10 to the 6th power, but the results don't show any change.

[image]

```
Energy['Energy Supply'].apply(lambda x: x*(10**6))
Energy.head()
```

[image]

Comment: Please note that in general, it is better to post example data / code as text instead of image - it's also more likely that you'll get a helpful answer then.

Comment: Regarding the Q, apply doesn't work in-place, you need to re-assign the returned series; `Energy['Energy Supply'] = Energy['Energy Supply'].apply(lambda x: x*(10**6))`.

Comment: assign the value to the column

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the `=` operator. DataFrames are not mutable like lists, therefore you have to store the value in the column: `Energy['Energy Supply'] = ...`.

```
Energy['Energy Supply'] = Energy['Energy Supply'].apply(lambda x: x*(10**6))
Energy.head()
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `apply`, just use compound assignment operators:

```
Energy['Energy Supply'] *= 1e6
```